# PHP Array and current()

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in the format

```
Array
(
    [/Callum/] => Array
        (
            [0] => ##chan1
        )
    [/Adam/] => Array
        (
            [0] => ##chan2
        )   
    [/Chris)/] => Array
        (
            [0] => ##chan1
        )
    [/Mike*/] => Array
        (
            [0] => ##chan3
        )
)
```

And from this I use the below code to try and get the id of the array that each channel features in.

```
foreach($array as $row)
{

    if (in_array($buf['channel'],$row))
    {
        $return = $return." ".current(array_keys($array,$row));
    }
}
```

My problem is that current() doesnt seem to work the way I am expecting it to. Currently if the $buf /Callum/ twice rather than /Callum/ and /Chris/

Comment: array_keys is going to return a NEW array each time, which will always have its internal pointer set to the FIRST element.

Comment: ahh, definatly explains why that wasn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not:

```
foreach($array as $key => $row)
{

    if (in_array($buf['channel'],$row))
    {
        $return = $return . " " . $key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
foreach($array is $id => $row){
    $return .=" ".$id;
}
```

edit:

```
foreach($array is $id => $row){
    if($row[0] == $buf['channel']){
        echo $key; //This is your key
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this to replace the entire foreach or just the internal if?

Comment: The whole thing. But remove the $return and add your if-statement again, I think I missunderstood you..i'll edit my ans..